# though this files (sic) in the face

Tags: meaning

*In August 2018, Hersh said “the story of novichok poisoning has not held up very well. He [Skripal] was most likely talking to British intelligence services about Russian organised crime”. He said the contamination of other victims was “suggestive ... of organised crime elements rather than state-sponsored actions – though this files (sic) in the face of the UK government's position.”*

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seymour_Hersh

Can you help me with understanding the passage in bold of the above text? Does it mean that this (the opinion that the death of Skripal was not a political murder) contradicts the position that holds the UK government?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an error somewhere along the reference chain, it should have said "flies", not "files". It is likely that a wikipedia editor noticed the error and inserted the *sic*.

"flies in the face of..." is an expression meaning something is the opposite of what is expected. In this particular case, Skripal's opinion is different than the British government (but it is not just different, it contradicts it).